# What is the acceptable verb to say that your battery has no energy?

Tags: word-choice

What is the acceptable verb to say that your battery has no energy (and I need to charge it)? 
I though on saying "My battery is finished" (and I need to charge it). This option is Ok? I've never saw English speakers in such situation so I didn't study from them about it.

Comment: Related: *[Any differences between my battery is dead and my battery runs out](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/70990)*. Also see at EL&U: *[Battery is flat](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/131427)* and *[“I have no charge on my cellphone” or “my cellphone is out of charge”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10084)*

Answer (score 2):

It is usual to say "The battery *died*." or "The battery is *dead*."

You could also say, the battery *drained*, but that is usually used when it is caused by something using a lot of its power.  For example, "I used the flashlight on my phone, and it *drained* the battery."

Answer (score 2):

In the UK, [flat](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/flat)- *(of a battery) fully discharged; dead*. For mobile phones, etc, dead is becoming more widely used.

Answer (score 1):

In the U.S., we usually say that the battery has *died,* or has "gone *dead."*

If I hear that the battery is *finished,* I think that it has been *charged* and *drained* (or *discharged*) so many times that it can no longer *hold a charge,* and is destined for the recycling heap.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the exact circumstances, your  battery could be

(completely) drained
dead
discharged

For a rechargeable battery as in a cell phone,  you probably want *(completely) drained*.

[Smartphone battery draining too fast?](https://www.androidpit.com/smartphone-battery-draining-too-fast-we-help-you-find-out-why)

For a rechargeable battery, I would not call it *dead* if it was still capable of being recharged.