# Does "my phone died" mean my phone is out of battery or my phone is broken?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, phrase-usage

The dictionary says

"**the phone is dead**" means [it's not working because of a lack of power](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/dead_1?q=dead)

and

"**the phone died**" means [it stopped working](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/die_1?q=die) (I don't understand "stop working" here means out of power or it is malfunctioned

Does "**my phone died**" mean my phone is out of battery or my phone is broken?

Comment: It could mean either, depending on the context, such as additional words - e.g. because a truck wheel crushed it, I dropped it down the toilet, I forgot to charge it last night and I've been playing games for 6 hours, I tried turning it on with the button, but nothing happens.

Comment: *Died* should mean something serious. But people exaggerate, so it just means they need a charge unless they say more.

Comment: [This question is focused on batteries](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/70990/41273) being dead, but the answer applies here too. I wonder if it's close enough for this to be a duplicate.

Comment: To distinguish between dead -  a flat battery (fixable) and a broken, it is common to refer to the latter case as "bricked". In other words it is as useful as a brick for making phone calls. But as others have commented, died / dead can mean either depending on the circumstances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common phrase and can mean both things. Most commonly, "My phone died" means that it ran out of battery and needs to be charged. This comes from the phrase "The battery died" or describing batteries as dead when they are out of power, which entered common speech before most batteries were rechargeable, when a battery running out of power was functionally the same as it being broken.

Saying an object has "died" can also mean that it is broken, usually beyond repair. Usually, context will make it clear if this is the meaning. Here are some examples:

> "My computer was purchased in 2011, it lasted a long time but when it died, I started looking for a new one."

> "I think my shoes are dying. The rubber has holes in it!"

> "My phone died when my 2-year-old son dropped it down the stairs."